# How do I change the appearance of some text in a textBox?

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm building a program similar to Messenger, sort of a chatting software.

I created a textBox to display the conversation log, and I want to make it look like this:

> **Nick1**:   Hi.
>
> **Nick2**:   Hello.

How do I make part of the text **bold**?
I also want to allow users to change their own font, font-color and so on...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RichTextBox` if building a Windows Forms or a WPF app.

Comment: I didn't really get it, how do I make a bold text with RichTextBox?

Comment: Use `RichTextBox` control to highlight/colorize parts of text. Here is an article that shows how to do it : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/duncanharris/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP112012005050840AM/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a RichTextEdit control, this control can take RTF format codes to easily format the text the way you want it.

eg.

```
\pard\plain\ltrpar\f0\fs14\sl240\slmult1\b\ Nick1.\par
\pard\plain\ltrpar\f0\fs14\sl240\slmult1\Hi
```

will show up as **Nick1** Hi

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using WPF I'd use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) to display the conversion. Then for each item I'd have a couple of `TextBlocks` one for the user name (which would be bold) and the other for the message.

Hope that helps.